# PHP & Pear::Mail Memory Exhaustion

Tags: php, loops, email, pear

**Solution below**

Hi guys. I've been trying different ways to approach this but still hitting the same error. I have a form where you can select some users email addresses and some pdf file and it will send to them. Problem is that PHP will throw an error because the script is using massive amounts of memory (over 90 meg). I have tried using mail() and now trying PEAR:Mail_Mime Is there another way I can do this?

```
include_once('Mail.php');
include_once('Mail/mime.php');
$from = "it@example.com";
$subject = $_POST[subject];
$text = $_POST[message];

if (count($_POST[emailEnq]) > 0) {
 foreach ($_POST[emailEnq] as $Ekey => $Evalue) {
  $message = new Mail_mime();
  $message->setTXTBody($text);
  if (count($_POST[emailFile]) > 0) {
   foreach ($_POST[emailFile] as $key => $value) {
    $filepath = "/home/mds07/console/admin/media/listings/" . $_POST[list_ID] . "/docs/";
    ////////////////////You will need to change the above line if the location of the PHP program ever moves////////////////////////////
    $fileatt = $filepath . $value;
    $message->addAttachment($fileatt);
   }
  }
  $body = $message->get();
  $extraheaders = array("From" => $from, "Subject" => $subject);
  $headers = $message->headers($extraheaders);
  $mail = Mail::factory("mail");
  $mail->send($Evalue, $headers, $body);
 }
}
```

---

**SOLUTION**
The following code is working with much better memory usage:

`$from = "it@example.com";`

echo 'From: '.$from."\n";
echo 'Subject: '.$_POST[subject]."\n";
echo 'Text: '.$_POST[message]."\n";

include_once('Mail.php');
include_once('Mail/mime.php');
$message = new Mail_mime();
$message->setTXTBody($_POST[message]);
if (count($_POST[emailFile]) > 0) {
    foreach ($_POST[emailFile] as $key => $filename) {
    $filepath = "/home/mds07/console/admin/media/listings/" . $_POST[list_ID] . "/";
    ////////////////////You will need to change the above line if the location of the PHP program ever moves////////////////////////////
    $fileatt = $filepath . $filename;
    $message->addAttachment($fileatt);
    echo 'Attached File: '.$filename."\n";
    }
}
$body = $message->get();
$extraheaders = array("From" => $from, "Subject" => $_POST[subject]);
$headers = $message->headers($extraheaders);
$mail = Mail::factory("mail");
if (count($_POST[emailEnq]) > 0) {
 foreach ($_POST[emailEnq] as $key => $recipient) {
  $mail->send($recipient, $headers, $body);
  echo 'Sent mail to: '.$recipient."\n";
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having used Pear::Mail_Mime I'd bet you run out of memory because you create a brand new `Mail_Mime()` object on every loop iteration, when it seems like it's the same in all of them.

Create as few as possible, taking it out of the outermost foreach.

Same for `$mail`. You can probably re-use the same `$mail` object and feed it new headers and body.

To make sure where your memory is used, surround the suspect lines with [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/memory_get_usage) and log its output to see the increase.

Comment: That's great. Consider adding your new working code to your question for a more complete look, instead of having it in an answer on its own.